# Trouble combining Linq Expressions into a Func

Tags: linq, nhibernate, ienumerable, iqueryable

I've been trying to factor some common lambda subexpressions out into reusable components and have hit a wall.  I'll show what I've done so far with a simplified example and hope one of you can shed some light.

My subexpressions are ultimately used in an NHibernate Query (IQueryable interface).  Here's an example:

```
var depts = session.Query<Department>().Where(d => d.employees.Any(ex1.AndAlso(ex2).Compile()));
```

**AndAlso** is an `Expression` extension that's defined like this (taken from an answer to a related **SO** question, with some minor adjustments):

```
public class ParameterRebinder : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression> _map;

    public ParameterRebinder(Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression> map)
    {
        _map = map ?? new Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression>();
    }
    public static Expression ReplaceParameters(Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression> map, Expression exp)
    {
        return new ParameterRebinder(map).Visit(exp);
    }
    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression p)
    {
        ParameterExpression replacement;
        if (_map.TryGetValue(p, out replacement))
        {
            p = replacement;
        }
        return base.VisitParameter(p);
    }
}

public static class ExpressionExtensions
{
    public static Expression<T> Compose<T>(this Expression<T> first, Expression<T> second, Func<Expression, Expression, Expression> merge)
    {
        // build parameter map (from parameters of second to parameters of first)
        var map = first.Parameters.Select((f, i) => new { f, s = second.Parameters[i] }).ToDictionary(p => p.s, p => p.f);
        // replace parameters in the second lambda expression with parameters from the first
        var secondBody = ParameterRebinder.ReplaceParameters(map, second.Body);
        // apply composition of lambda expression bodies to parameters from the first expression 
        return Expression.Lambda<T>(merge(first.Body, secondBody), first.Parameters);
    }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> AndAlso<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> first, Expression<Func<T, bool>> second)
    {
        return first.Compose(second, Expression.AndAlso);
    }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> OrElse<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> first, Expression<Func<T, bool>> second)
    {
        return first.Compose(second, Expression.OrElse);
    }
}
```

All would be well except that the **Any** call is an `IEnumerable` call, not an `IQueryable` call, so it expects a `Func` argument rather than an `Expression`.  To that end I call `Compile()` on the combined `Expression`, but then I get the following run-time error:

> Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ParserException: Could not parse expression
>   'c.employees.Any(value(System.Func`2[Entities.Domain.Department,System.Boolean]))':
>   Object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression' cannot be
>   converted to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'. If you
>   tried to pass a delegate instead of a LambdaExpression, this is not
>   supported because delegates are not parsable expressions.
>       at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.MethodCallExpressionParser.CreateExpressionNode(Type nodeType, MethodCallExpressionParseInfo parseInfo, Object[] additionalConstructorParameters)
>   at
>   Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.MethodCallExpressionParser.Parse(String associatedIdentifier, IExpressionNode source, IEnumerable`1 arguments, MethodCallExpression expressionToParse)
>   at
>   Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.ExpressionTreeParser.ParseMethodCallExpression(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression, String associatedIdentifier)
>   at
>   Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.QueryParser.GetParsedQuery(Expression expressionTreeRoot)
>   at
>   Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionTreeVisitors.SubQueryFindingExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitExpression(Expression expression)
>   at
>   Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitLambdaExpression(LambdaExpression expression)
>   at
>   Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.MethodCallExpressionParser.ProcessArgumentExpression(Expression argumentExpression)
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>
>   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.MethodCallExpressionParser.Parse(String associatedIdentifier, IExpressionNode source, IEnumerable`1 arguments, MethodCallExpression expressionToParse)
>   at
>   Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.ExpressionTreeParser.ParseMethodCallExpression(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression, String associatedIdentifier)
>   at
>   Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.QueryParser.GetParsedQuery(Expression expressionTreeRoot)
>   at NHibernate.Linq.NhRelinqQueryParser.Parse(Expression expression) in
>   NhRelinqQueryParser.cs: line 39

...and so on for the rest of the stack.

My conundrum seems to be that one can't combine `Funcs`, only `Expressions` -- which produces another `Expression`.  But one can't hand an `Expression` to `IEnumerable.Any()` -- only a `Func`.  But then the `Func` produced by `Expression.Compile()` seems to be the wrong kind...

Any ideas?

Michael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
Func<T1, TResult> func = t => t == 5;
Expression<Func<T1, TResult>> expression = t => t == 5;
```

With this code, `func` will be a reference to compiled code, while `expression` will be a reference to an abstract syntax tree representing the lambda expression. Calling `Compile()` on the expression will return compiled code functionally equivalent to `func`.

What type of expression is contained in the compiled code is irrelevant - the LINQ providers simply cannot decode compiled code. They rely on walking the abstract syntax tree represented by the `Expression<Func<...>>` type.

In your case, you apply `Any()` on `d.employees`. Since `employees` is an  `IEnumerable<T>`, you will get the version of `Any()` that expects to get compiled code that it can run. Note that `Any()` is also available for queryables, and will in that case accept an expression.

You could try `AsQueryable()`, but I'm not sure it will work:

```
session.Query<Department>()
       .Where(d => d.employees.AsQueryable().Any(ex1.AndAlso(ex2)));
```

Otherwise, you have to rewrite it without using any.

Comment: You're correct, and as you can see from my own answer I tried inserting AsQueryable() and that worked.  Unfortunately, although it worked for the trivial case I presented here I'm still getting an exception with the real code.  I'm going to fiddle with it some more, and I may be back here with a follow-up question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It occurred to me that, given that the problem revolved around the fact that `IEnumerable` methods take `Func` arguments, if I could get *d.employees* (in my example) to be an `IQueryable` rather than an `IEnumerable` then its `Any` would take an `Expression` and I'd be done.

So, I tried inserting an `.AsQueryable()` after *d.employees*, and that worked!